# Correct way to disable html form elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html, button

I have the following code that finds button elements by an HTML5 data-attribute called **data-button-day** which has values of the days of the week.

For example

```
<button type="button" data-button-day="sunday" class="btn btn-danger btn-block sunday">
```

What I would like to do, is when a button is clicked, all elements with a data-attribute of **data-day="dayOfWeek"** are either disabled or enabled depending on the class of the button.

```
<script>
// this finds the correct button and works as expected

    $( "button" ).click(function() {
        $( this ).toggleClass( "btn-default btn-danger" );
        var day = $(this).data("button-day");
        toggle(day);
    });

this is called, however it produces an error as it isn't the right code to use

    function toggle(day) {
        $('[data-day="' + day + '"]').each().disabled();
    }
</script>
```

I get

`TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.call')`

Comment: I still get ```TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'b.call')```

Comment: What makes a `<div>` "disabled" or "enabled"? Note that there is no `disabled()` function in jQuery. Also, see the correct syntax for [`each()`](https://api.jquery.com/each/).

Comment: It's not the ```<div>```s that are enabled or disabled. It is the Form elements.

Comment: It looks like you are selecting and attempting to disable `<div>` elements: `$('div[data-day="' + day + '"]').each().disabled();`

Comment: @showdevyou my friend are genius. Always great to have a fresh pair of eyes.

Comment: How do I toggle the disabled/enabled based on the class of the button?

Comment: Using class will require more code than a data-* attribute. I'd stick with the data unless you have a really good reason not to use it.

Comment: I don't mind how it is done, I have a row of elements that I want to toggle enabled/disabled depending on the state of the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need .each() and each requires parameters. Also, drop the "div" from your selector.

To get toggle behavior just add/remove a disabled class.

```js
$("button").click(function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("btn-default btn-danger");
    var day = $(this).data("button-day");
    var isDisabled = $(this).hasClass("disabled");
    if (isDisabled) {
        $(this).removeClass("disabled");
    }
    else {
        $(this).addClass("disabled");
    }
    toggle(day, !isDisabled);
});


function toggle(day, disabled) {
    $('[data-day = "' + day + '"]').prop("disabled", disabled);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" data-button-day="sunday" class="btn btn-danger btn-block sunday">Sunday</button>
<input type="text" data-day="sunday" />
<input type="text" data-day="monday" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code as my buttons were being disabled and remaining that way.

I'll leave this here for my future reference.

```
<script>
    $("button").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("btn-default btn-danger");
        var day = $(this).data("button-day");
        var isDisabled = $(this).hasClass("btn-danger");
        toggle(day, isDisabled);
    });

    function toggle(day, disabled) {
        $('[data-day = "' + day + '"]').prop("disabled", disabled);
    }
</script>
```